# Designing a Multi Language Site

Tags: wordpress, web, multilingual

I am presently developing a trilingual website using wordpress, but am presently confused as to how I should complete the design. As the entire site should be editted through a single admin page, how should I create a new article and include that only for language A for example and not for language B? Or else should I develop 3 different wordpress sites for each language, and thereby have 3 different themes as well?

Any ideas on how this could be acocmplished

Answer (score 0):

Check out plugins like http://wpml.org , they should do the trick. Works like a charm!

Comment: No, that wouldnt work for me. As I need to use English, Sinhala and Tamil, and all the 3 content would be included manually from the admin create content page

Comment: Which is wat multiple plugins can do... I used it two years ago for a multilanguage website, worked fine. 
Other option is hardcore code it, lot's of tutorials for that

Comment: yes I am aiming at the second option you mentioned, but couldnt find any related tutorials as you mentioned. Therefore how should I begin the development, in English first and then including others when adding content etc or

Answer (score 0):

I am also developing multi language site in Wordpress and I am using Free plugin [qTranslate](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/qtranslate/).

You add languages you want and other settings under **Admin >Settings > Languages** and then when you edit Post/Page you switch between Languages same way as you switch between HTML and Visual by using Tabs.